# Add tkinter's intvar to an integer

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm having some trouble adding a value taken from an Entry box and adding it to an existing number. In this case, I want the value of the "change speed" box to be added to the robots current speed. When run, my code produces an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'IntVar'.

Below is the code that produces the entry box:

```
change_speed_entry = ttk.Entry(main_frame, width=5)  # Entry box for linear speed
change_speed_entry.grid()
data = tkinter.IntVar()
change_speed_entry['textvariable'] = data
```

And next is where I try to manipulate the result. This is a method within a class. All other methods of the class work correctly:

```
def changeSpeed(self, delta_speed):
    self.speed += delta_speed
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to first invoke the `.get` method of `IntVar`:

```
def changeSpeed(self, delta_speed):
    self.speed += delta_speed.get()
```

which returns the variable's value as an integer.

Since I don't have your full code, I wrote a small script to demonstrate:

```
from Tkinter import Entry, IntVar, Tk

root = Tk()

data = IntVar()

entry = Entry(textvariable=data)
entry.grid()

def click(event):
    # Get the number, add 1 to it, and then print it
    print(data.get() + 1)

# Bind the entrybox to the Return key
entry.bind("<Return>", click)

root.mainloop()
```

When you run the script, a small window appears that has an entrybox.  When you type a number in that entrybox and then click `Return`, the script gets the number stored in `data` (which will be the number you typed in), adds 1 to it, and then prints it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the code defining `.speed` or `delta_speed`, so I'm guessing here.  Try:

```
    self.speed += delta_speed.get()
                             ^^^^^^
```

**If** `delta_speed` is an `IntVar`, `.get()` will retrieve its value as a Python int.