# How do I keep value of variable after calling another class via tkinter widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am quite new to tkinter, and I'm struggling with my code, which is supposed initiate a button and entry box in tkinter, and then wait for the user to input "train", click the button, and add 1 to the *training* variable, erase all widgets. Then, the code should come back to the while loop, re-initiate the widgets and repeat, while saving the training variable. However, when I run my code, the loop goes through once, and even if the user enters "train" more than once, the variable stays at 1. I've tried making the variable *training* an IntVar() type, but then I can't add 1 to it in the line "training=training+1". Any ideas?

```
import tkinter as tk
def main():
    training=0
    x="train"
    while(x=="train"):
        x=tk.Entry(root)
        x.pack()
        tr=tk.Button(root, text='Ok', command=lambda: amount(training,x.get()))
        tr.pack()

def amount(training,x):
    if(x=="train"):
        training=training+1
        list = root.slaves()
        for slave in list:
            slave.forget()
 main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719577/add-tkinters-intvar-to-an-integer

Comment: Once you see that other question, you can just do the same thing and call the 'set' function for IntVar

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, but the problem of my while loop not repeating still remains.

Comment: The reason your loop only runs once is that you do `while(x=="train"):`, then change `x` from the string `'train'` to an `Entry`, so it's no longer equal to `'train'`. But if you didn't misuse the same variable to mean two different things like this, it would just loop forever, creating as many entries and buttons as it can until raising an exception. I think you really need to read a tutorial on tkinter, because this is so far from being meaningful code that it's hard to explain how to "fix" it.

Comment: I understand, I don't want my loop to go on forever. I want the variable to be equal to "train" initially, and then I want my entry widget to be checked every time the user clicks the "ok" button, and whatever they entered should be set equal to the _x_ variable. Then, if that new _x_ variable value still equals "train", I want the loop to repeat, therefore triggering the amount function, causing 1 to be added to the _training_ variable, and if the user wishes, they can enter "train" again, so that the amount function gets triggered _again_. Sorry, I must've explained this badly.